# HQL update query in grails integraion test

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, grails-orm

Grails/Groovy project with Hibernate domain classes and integration tests.
I have two classes:

```
First{
    id
    SomeClassAlsoSevaedInDB porp1
    SomeClassAlsoSevaedInDB porp2
    String somefield;
}

Second {
    id
    First first
    String somefield2;
}
```

I want to delete only object of First type, due to I have about 20kk First objects in db, I execute hsql statement like

```
firstToDelete = [1,2,3]
Second.executeUpdate("Update Second set first = null where first.id in (1,2,3)")
First.findAllByIdInList(firstToDelete)*.delete()
```

With this behavior i have error:

```
deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [First]
```

If i switch hql query to update Second objects it works fine

```
Second.findAllByFirstInList(First.findAllByIdInList(firstToDelete)).each {
    it.first = null
    it.save()
}
First.findAllByIdInList(firstToDelete)*.delete()    //  works fine
```

But i need HQL for better perfomance

I tried do this:

```
def listSecond = Second.findAllByFirstInList(First.findAllByIdInList(firstToDelete))
Second.executeUpdate("Update Second set first = null where first.id in (1,2,3)")
First.findAllByIdInList(firstToDelete)*.delete()
println listSecond.first // return Not Empty list(should be empty)
```

I think root case of issue is object related with deleted First object still contains in memory(cached or something else) and before save something do with this, but i don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the Firsts with HQL too, they will not be loaded so you will certainly not get an exception related to cascading.

Comment: I can't do this because i need Cascading removed, First class have also other classes saved in DB